# Shared Element Activity Transition having with weird performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I am using a shared element transition between two activities. I am using this link for animation. Integrated this.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

I am getting something like this. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this kind of screen for a second.  Animation in not smooth, but when we press back button back animation as expected smooth.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UuVT.png)

Comment: element transitions require Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above and will be ignored for any lower API versions. Which version are you using can u share some code what you have done

Comment: Yes, I am supporting 28 and above but still facing problem.

Comment: Can you provide some source code of your implementation?

Comment: Please check the image which I am getting. In the First activity, my icon is at bottom center and second activity my icon is a top center When an animation starts it show 4 icon and some weird background. Please check.